# Regular Expressions re.findall()

Tags: python, regex

I have a function which takes a count and a string as input. It should return a list of all words in that string of length count, and greater. Python however doesn't recognise my variable and returns an empty list.

```
def word_number(count, string):
    return re.findall(r'\w{count,}', string)
```

How do I pass in the variable 'count' so that the function returns words of count and longer?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `printf` style formatting:

```
re.findall(r'\w{%s,}' % count, string)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that was killing me!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [str.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples) to achieve your goal.

```
def word_number(count, string):
    return re.findall(r'\w{{{0},}}'.format(count), string)
```

Comment: Need to double up the outermost braces for this to work: `r'\w{{{0},}}'`